# Replacing relay for solid state alternative to detect if a connector is plugged in

Tags: relay, connector, detection

I'm adding an extra LED light to the trunk of my car stuck to the removable shelf through a magnetic connector (Aux connector). I want the original light not to work if the new light (LED) is plugged in.

The input to the circuit is 0V when the trunk is closed or 12-14V if the trunk is open. My idea is for the connector to the new light to have tree wires that, when connected will trigger a relay to disconnect the original OEM light, while, at the same time powering the new light. My circuit idea is as follows:

[image: Original Circuit Idea]

I would like to not depend on a relay and go full solid state, but I do not know how to implement this solution or a similar one that would render the same result.

Thanks for the help

Comment: a solid state automotive relay would be the same as a mechanical relay on the outside

Comment: I believe automotive solid state relays do not have a NC output

Comment: If you set it up so the relay is only powered when the aux LED light is connected then there is no issue at all.

Comment: @SolarMike I don't see how that could be done. At the end of the day, I'm using the relay to turn off the integrated lamp. Can you provide a bit more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep it simple:

Use a phone jack with a switch on the car, and a phone plug on the shelf. When the plug is in the jack, the switch opens and removes power from the built-in light.

2. Keep it even simpler:

Let the built-in light remain on, even if the shelf plug is mated.

3. Keep it even "more simpler":

Mount an off-the-shelf, battery operated lamp on the shelf. When you need the light, turn it on. No cables, no messing with the original wiring of the car.

Comment: Phone jack is not good for automotive application because of vibration.

Comment: Well, I guess I could, but that is completely changing the scope of the question and the approach to a solution.